# OnClick button create a dynamic div in Rails (using java script or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a dynamic div by using jquery How to do that?
OnClick plus button it should be create same div elements

example:

```
<%= form_for  @expense_fills, url: view_excess_path, method: :post do |f| %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title text-center"> </h3>
                </div>
            <div class="box-body ">
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20%" >
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <%= f.collection_select :id, ExpenseCategory.order(:name),:id,:name, { include_blank: false},{ class:' inputsm form-control '} %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback ">
              <%= f.text_field :amount, class:'inputsm form-control', placeholder: 'Amount' %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <%= f.submit "submit",class:'btn btn-default next-btn'  %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-right " style="margin-right: 5%; border-radius: 50%;">
            <%= f.button "+" , class: 'btn btn-default  ' %>
          </div>

        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Your help saves life, must appreciated.

Thanks lot in advance

Comment: can you please mention which div element? Same div element means you want to make a copy of .row element? and please share what have you done till now

Comment: Did you tried anything:- `$('.pull-right').on('click',function(){$(this).closest('.row').clone().insertAfter($(this).closest('.row'));});`

Comment: Yes , I want to copy of row elements only

Comment: @AlivetoDie You are right, my mistake sorry, It's working nice but that button redirecting to next page i don't want that. (please add that to answer I would like to accept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On click of the button

1.clone the div

2.insert the clone after initial div.

Do like below (hard-coded value example):-

```js
$(document).on('click','.pull-right',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();//stop redirection
  var cont = $(this).closest('.row').clone(); //clone the row
  //first remove button and then add it after initial row
  $(cont).find(".pull-right").remove().end().insertAfter($(this).closest('.row'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title text-center"> </h3>
            </div>
        <div class="box-body ">
            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 20%" >
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    1.first
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback ">
          2000
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type ="submit">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right " style="margin-right: 5%; border-radius: 50%;">
        +
      </div>

    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working fine but it  redirecting to next page. Can you explain little bit more please?

Comment: I have edited my code for redirection prevention. Please have a look (i have added `e.preventDefault()`)

Comment: Perfect dude, but its also copying my plus(+) button. what change should i have to do? (sorry i am newbie to both java script and rails)

Comment: Great job. Its working perfectly as I am expected. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @BharatMane  glad to help you :):).

Comment: @BharatMane  please ask a new question for that.

Comment: i posted the new question please have look once [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000761/ror-5-how-to-stop-auto-persisting-previous-copy-of-java-script-in-rails-form]